# onclick Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property

Tags: javascript, html, onclick, buttonclick

## Project setting

- Webstorm 2017.2
- Language javascript, html

## Project structure

```
.
├── Prototype
│   ├── Core
│   │   └── WebBroadcast.js
│   └── index.html
├── README.md
```

## Source code

### index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Web player prototype</title>
    <script src="Core/WebBroadcast.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <button type="button" onclick="webConnection.connectToServer()">Connect</button>
        <button type="button" onclick="webConnection.disconnectFromServer()">Disconnect</button>
    </div>
    <canvas id="webPlayer" width="640" height="480" style="border:1px solid #000000;"></canvas>

    <script>
        webConnection = WebConnection("ws://192.168.33.30/jpeg/1/jpeg_stream.websock", "admin", "admin", "webPlayer");
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

## WebBroadcast.js

```
function WebConnection(address, userName, userPassword) {
    console.log("add: " + address + " name: " + userName + " pwd: " + userPassword)
}

WebConnection.prototype.connectToServer = function () {
    console.log("connect")
}

WebConnection.prototype.disconnectFromServer = function () {
    console.log("disconnect")
}
```

## Expected behavior

```
add: ws://192.168.33.30/jpeg/1/jpeg_stream.websock name: admin pwd: admin
connect
```

## Actual behavior

```
add: ws://192.168.33.30/jpeg/1/jpeg_stream.websock name: admin pwd: admin
onclick Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'connectToServer' of undefined
```

This is my first try of javascript project. 
I need you guys help.

Comment: Shouldn't you have a port open for websockets?

Comment: It&#39;s not .prototype at least that never works for me. Try WebConnection.__proto__.

Comment: @NewToJS You know, this source code not need web socket port yet.

Comment: @TyQ. not working

Comment: @TyQ. if I change button tag script `webConnection.connectToServer()` -> `WebConnection.connectToServer()` then I can see connect message, but I can't get data that I passed as parameter (address, user name, etc...)

`
add: ws://192.168.33.30/jpeg/1/jpeg_stream.websock name: admin pwd: admin
onclick Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'connectToServer' of undefined
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guys I found the problem.

## Original

```
webConnection = WebConnection("ws://192.168.33.30/jpeg/1/jpeg_stream.websock", "admin", "admin", "webPlayer");
```

## Fixed

```
webConnection = new WebConnection("ws://192.168.33.30/jpeg/1/jpeg_stream.websock", "admin", "admin", "webPlayer");
```

It cause by `new`